# How to get weights from keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a 2 layered neural network for MNIST dataset and I want to get weights from my model.

I found a similar question her on SO and I tried this,

```
model.get_weights()
```

But It returned 11 values when I check the `len(model.get_weights())` Isn't it suppose to return 3 weights? I have even disabled bias.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape = (28, 28)))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', use_bias=False,))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', use_bias=False,))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', use_bias=False,))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

result = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=0.25, epochs=10, 
                   batch_size=128, verbose=1)
```

Comment: You get weights for each layer you have. Where do you get 3?

Comment: @cs95 What counts as a layer? How can it be 11 then? I only have 3 dense layers right? I'm new to neural nets.

Comment: Anything defined in [`tf.keras.layers`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers) is a layer. Basically, anything that has weights or parameters you can configure is a layer.

Comment: @cs95 Thank but that still makes it 8 right? `(flatten, dense, bn, dropout, dense, bn, dropout and dense)`

Comment: perhaps the activation='relu' counts as a separate layer. Or there are other weights corresponding to the optimiser or loss. I am not as familiar with TensorFlow keras API as I would like.

Comment: You should instead iterate through each layer in the model and get the weights of each layer individually.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal Yeah that would really help. I didn't know we could do that. Can you post a sample example on how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the weights of a particular [layer](https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/), you could retrieve this layer by using its name and call `get_weights` on it (as [shubham-panchal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10878733/shubham-panchal) said in its [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56754089/how-to-get-weights-from-keras-model/56756872#comment100069446_56754089)).

For example:

```
model.get_layer('dense').get_weights()
```

or

```
model.get_layer('dense_2').get_weights()
```

You could go though the `layers` of your model and retrieve its name and weights:

```
{layer.name: layer.get_weights() for layer in model.layers}
```